# Is joyride responsive?

Tags: zurb-joyride, zurb-foundation-5

I have recently started playing around with joyride. It is superb. However, I am having some major responsive issues. When I resize my browser, the tip position changes. For instance, when the original position is 'top' it suddenly changes to 'bottom' when I resize the browser.

I have looked everywhere for a solution but unable to find why this is happening.

Is anyone experiencing this issue and/or know a way around this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Responsive web design is not about manually resizing your browser, the foundation needs to load to calculte the co-ords of the page?